# Для чего используют Laravel blade stack?

Tags: php, laravel

Очень мало информации и примеров в интернете, так и не понял
что делают  Laravel blade  стеки.

Можно ли обойтись без них использовать только `@yield`?
Где именно нужно  использовать стеки ?

Если есть хорошие ссылки буду рад посмотреть.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Comment: "You may push to a stack as many times as needed." и

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я как всегда объясняю вам лару :)

Лара дает 2 инструмента `@stack` (и его `@push`+`@endpush`) и `@yeild` (и его `@section`+`@endsection`).

Различие в том, что в `@push`+`@endpush` можно дописывать, тогда как `@section`+`@endsection` нельзя, один раз создался, последующие попытки будут проигнорированы.

```
@push('my_test')
    123
@endpush
@push('my_test')
    123
@endpush

@stack('my_test')
```

Результат будет: `123123`

У `@yeild` будет: `123`

---

P.S. Однако у `@yeild` есть метод `@append` который создаст такой-же результат.

Запутано, но вот так вот, на любой вкус :)